# Python Code to play a video in Nvidia Jetson Nano

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-deepstream

I am using Nvidia Jetson Nano to stream and play videos through a python code.

But what I have seen is that my CPU usage is going pretty high, and it is not having much impact on its GPU.
So this will cause me a problem as I will not be able to utilize my GPU properly.

My purpose of using this device is to get better speed and performance, but I found that I am not able to utilize my GPU well.
Please someone help me what I can do such that my code will be processed mostly on GPU thus removing burden from CPU.

I am using cv2 module of python to play the video.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to be more selective on what OpenCV modules you use. You need to use OpenCV modules with CUDA support if you want them to utilize the GPU.

Follow for example this guide to get started -> https://learnopencv.com/getting-started-opencv-cuda-module/